# Using $cordovaCamera to get a base64 string is not working. Always returns URI?

Tags: angularjs, base64, ionic-framework, firebase, ngcordova

Using the following settings for `$cordovaCamera`, I get the error that `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`, `Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA` and `Camera.EncodingType.JPEG` are not defined, but when I use there integer values of 0,1 and 0 I can get past the error; however, the image is not returned as a `base64` string rather the URI of the image.

```
var options = {
  quality : 75,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 100,
  targetHeight: 100,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
};
```

I'm trying to save the image to Firebase, but all I can teem to get is the temp file location of the image, which is pretty much worthless.

my function:

```
var getPhoto = function() {
    Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageData) {
      console.log(imageData);
      $scope.lastPhoto = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      console.err(err);
    }, {
      quality : 75,
      destinationType : 0,
      sourceType : 1,
      allowEdit : true,
      encodingType: 0,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      targetWidth: 500,
      targetHeight: 500,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    });
};
```

where `Camera` is a service I defined:

```
.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
        console.log('this CAMERA service is getting called')
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        console.log('RESULT in SERVICE', result);
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}]);
```

What am I missing my result returns `data:image/jpeg;base64,file://somethingSomething`

How can i get the base64 value of the image taken so that i can effectively save it to Firebase?

Comment: You should not get `Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA and Camera.EncodingType.JPEG are not defined` , did you check that if plugin is proper installed in your project ?

Comment: problem is that your options are not getting passed, result you are getting is with default options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
.factory('CamService', ['$q', function ($q) {

    return {
        GetPicture: function (options) {
            var cameraOptions = {
                quality: 40,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                correctOrientation: true,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
                targetHeight: 720
            };
            var q = $q.defer();

            navigator.camera.getPicture(function (result) {
                // Do any magic you need
                q.resolve(result);
            }, function (err) {
                q.reject(err);
            }, cameraOptions);

            return q.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

And in your Controller

```
CamService.GetPicture().then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("data:image/jpeg;base64," + data);

        }, function (err) {
            console.err(err);
        });
```

Your way the options are not considered when calling the Service

Comment: im getting the error of : Plugin 'CDVCamera' has a pending operation, memory purge is delayed for didReceiveMemoryWarning. when i choose the photo after i take it.

Comment: Well this error happens due to a Memory Problem when taking multiple high res images so what you could do is set the quality lower and try again another possibility would be to change Data Url to FileUrl but since you need the base 64 this isnt really an option sadly